# Identify rows in an aggregate table that have only 1 occurrence

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I've an aggregated table as shown below in the image (along with the code to get it).

I need to find number of Id which is occurring only once. How can I achieve this in SQL Server?

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images for code or data - how do you expect us to copy and paste it out to assist you?

Comment: Thank you Dale, I was trying to do the same.

Comment: Please do... add your code and data as text and then use the code format option in the editor.

Comment: Please ensure you have both sample data *AND* expected results so its clear what you wish to accomplish. And as already said please add as text not image.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select . . .
      from . . .
      group by . . .
      having count(*) = 1
     ) x;
```

The `. . .` is for the components of your query.

Comment: If you see the above image, I want to get those Id which occur only once in the output table.

Comment: Your specific question is:  "I need to find number of Id which is occurring only once".  That sounds like a count to me.  In any case, the subquery -- or your query with the `having` clause -- does what you want.

Comment: my question is that after I get this table, I need to Identify Ids that have only 1 NaicsCodeValue

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to count how many `id`s appear only once in the results of your existing query, in other words how many `id`s have just one distinct  `NaicsCodeValue`.

One option is to use window functions:

```
select count(*)
from (
    select 
        Id, 
        NaicsCodeValue, 
        max(...) max_emp,
        count(*) over(partition by id) cnt
    from ...
    group by Id, NaicsCodeValue
) t
where cnt = 1
```

If you want the entire rows from the original query:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        Id, 
        NaicsCodeValue, 
        max(...) max_emp,
        count(*) over(partition by id) cnt
    from ...
    group by Id, NaicsCodeValue
) t
where cnt = 1
```

If you just want the count, this can also be written by aggregating by `id` and filtering by the number of distinct `NaicsCodeValue`:

```
select count(*)
from (
    select 1 
    from ...
    group by Id
    having count(distinct NaicsCodeValue) = 1
) t
```

This is a bit more different from your original query, but looks to me like a simpler manner to get the result that you expect (*if* I understood it correctly).

Comment: Your second code does work. However, would it be possible to get only those Id which has only one value of RepNaicscode.   For example, Id = 10 has 3 different Naicscodevalue, so it shouldn't be counted

Comment: @Paras: that's what the query does... It gives you only records whose `id`s has only one `NaicsCodeValue`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. Would it still work if I had to find max value of 2 columns, for example, something like this:                                                           
    select *
from (
    select 
        Id, 
        NaicsCodeValue as RepNaicsCode, 
        max(ThisBusinessEmployeeCount) as max_emp,
        MAX (ThisBusinessSalesVolume) as max_sales,
        count(*) over(partition by id) cnt
    from #LeftIds
    group by Id, NaicsCodeValue
) t
where cnt = 1

Comment: I just rechecked the code. It gives the same answer irrespective of whether we take the maximum value of ThisEmployeeBusinessCount variable. I want only 1 maximum value of the max_emp, which would have only one Naics code. It can be the case that tmaximum values are same, however NaicsCodes are different.

Comment: so basically it is, for each Id, I check the maximum value of employee count and print the corresponding NaicsCode if only 1 maximum. However maximum values are same, so multiple Naicscode are printed.